# Azure Pipeline Trigger

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I've recently built a pipeline in ADF. I placed a trigger that launches it every day at a specific time.

But if my computer goes off, the pipeline doesn't trigger. Is it necessary to keep the computer on, knowing that everything happens in the cloud? If that is the case, can you advise the alternative?

Comment: Hey, can you tell what type of trigger are you using? And whether the pipeline is not getting triggered or it is failing due to some reason?

Comment: Hi Tarik, you are correct that your local machine should have nothing to do with the scheduled trigger. Can you verify that you have Published the pipeline and trigger?

Comment: @nandan, it's a schedule trigger.if i keep my machine on, the pipeline triggers successfully, but if it's off or i'm disconnected to the VPN, nothing happens

Comment: @JoelCochran thank you. yes it's published, if i keep my machine on, the pipeline triggers successfully, but if it's off or i'm disconnected to the VPN, nothing happens

Comment: Can you show the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to keep the computer on

No this is unnecessary. Once you published the whole data factory, there should be no relationship with your own machine.

Refresh your page, and then see whether the trigger is still in the data factory.

If still not work, please contact technical support of microsoft.